# Continuous range for HorizontalSlider

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am making use of a Dojo HorizontalSlider [in my app.](http://languagesofaustralia.com.s3.amazonaws.com/SimonJacksonFiles/filterStrain2.html)

Currently when you drag the slider it jumps in 1 step integer intervals between the range I have specified.  I need it to be more precise and allow for floating values (e.g. 3.24 - 7.51).

The above link is just a sample with a public service.  My range is actually between 0-10.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="pixelSlider" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider" data-dojo-props="showButtons:'false', intermediateChanges:'false', slideDuration:'0'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalRule"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  var slider = registry.byId("pixelSlider");     
  var sliderMin = 0;  
  var sliderMax = 4000;  
  slider.minimum = sliderMin;
  slider.maximum = sliderMax;
  slider.value = [sliderMin, sliderMax];
```

I have little Javascript experience but have been struggling to adapt the app to reflect the behaviour I need.  I saw from the [dojo samples](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html) you can specify a slider to use discreteValues, but I am not doing this, so assumed it would then allow for non-integer ranges to be chosen?  Can someone put me out of my misery.  I am sure this must be a simple one.

**EDIT**
Attempted using discrete values but no cigar:

[image]

Comment: you want decimal values flaot values  ?

Comment: It's probably not related but you shouldn't be using slider.minimum = 0 etc in dojo 1. You need to use .set('minimum', 0) or pass them in as constructor arguments

Answer (score 1):

I think discrete values is what you want. Discrete values doesn't mean specifying a list of possible values but the number of values that can be on the slider. So if you want to slide between 1 and 10 with two decimal places set the discreteValues to 100.

Edit:

Whilst that might work range slider appears to support continuous values out of the box so I am unclear what you are doing wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/d43azsvw/

```
require([
"dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider",
"dijit/form/HorizontalRuleLabels"
], function (HorizontalRangeSlider, HorizontalRuleLabels) {

var min = 0;
var max = 10;

var slider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
    minium: min,
  maximum: max,
    style: "width:300px;",
}, "yearSliderNode");
slider.onChange = function(evt) {
console.log(evt)
}

var sliderLabel = new HorizontalRuleLabels({
    container: 'topDecoration',
    minimum: min,
    maximum: max,
    count: 11,
    numericMargin: 0,

    constraints: {pattern: '#.#'}
   }, "sliderLabelsNode");

  });
```